# How to get the value form SimpleSAML_Session Object

Tags: php, single-sign-on

The saml Session is SimpleSAML_Session Object

```
          $data =
          (
           [trackid:SimpleSAML_Session:private] => 3eb
           [idp:SimpleSAML_Session:private] => https://abs.com
           [authenticated:SimpleSAML_Session:private] => 1
           [attributes:SimpleSAML_Session:private] => Array
          (
               [firstName] => Array
              (
                [0] => Aravind
              )

             [lastName] => Array
              (
                [0] => M
              )

             [email] => Array
            (
                [0] => aravind.muthu@abc.com
            )

    )
```

Here i need to take email value . How do i have parse the SAMLobj.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Friends , 
I got solution for this  . 
$data is an SAML object , we can use $data->getAttributes() to get the  values from it .
Refer http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.6/simplesamlphp-sp-api
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code we can get the values from SAML object.

```
$values = $data->getAttributes();  

Now $values contains an array values .
```

For more info  goto  http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.6/simplesamlphp-sp-api

Thanks